# Node.js Is Not Catching This module's Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, try-catch, imgur

here is module

```
const imgurUser = require('imgur-user');
```

and this module when did not found an imgur user throws error.
but I cant Catch the error:

```
try{
    imgurUser('dsfksdkfsdf4').then(res => {
    console.log(res);
        
    })
}catch(err){
    console.log("error")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe what'll solve your problem is to put a catch block after the .then:

```
imgurUser('user')
  .then(res => {
    console.log(res);
  })
.catch(err => {
  console.error(err);
})
```

If you want to, you could use async/await. Like this:

```
const fetchImgurUser = async (user) => {
  try {
    const res = await imgurUser(user);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
}

fetchImgurUser('user');
```

Comment: it was not worket but I saw the codes of module and it has been fixed.